# Integrating user id into creation of a new object in an Activerecord database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Creating a simple flashcard app with a single has many, belongs to relationship:

`card belongs_to :user
 user has_many :cards`

Because of AR conventions, have set up a validation for user_id in the cards table to reflect the association:

`create_table "cards", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string  "word_text",    null: false
     t.string  "meaning_text", null: false
     t.integer "user_id",      null: false
   end`

Now, running feature tests on the creation of a new flashcard, running into trouble because i don't know how to ensure that the user_id column in the newly created object gets filled in with user.id... tried adding this to my form, but nothing seems to work...

```

```
<%= form_for @card do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :word_text %>
   <%= f.text_field :word_text %>

  <%= f.label :meaning_text %>
  <%= f.text_field :meaning_text %>

  <%= f.label :user_id %>
  <%= f.number_field :user_id %>

<%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

```

I know that this is the error because when I enter `@card.save!` in rails console i get this error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank`

If I'm signed in okay, should the user id be automatically used to create the new object?

Very new to rails and can't seem to decipher what's going on here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you are creating card for associated user then use `hidden_field` for `user_id` or append the `user_id` with the `params` in the controller.

Comment: Don't use a `hidden_field`, worst idea ever because it can be manually change by the end-user. This means I could create Card belonging to someone else. You should set the user's id in the `create` action, appending it to the `params[:card]` received.

Comment: thanks for replying. MrYoshiji, I believe I tried this at one point, appending to the card_params in the private section of my cards_controller so that it looked like this:

`
  def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:word_text, :meaning_text, :user_id user_id)
  end`         but is that not right? should i append in the create method itself?     `@card = Card.new(params[:card])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `create` action like this in your CardsController:

```
def create
  card = Card.new(card_params)
  if card.save
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    redirect_to some_other_path
  end
end
```

You should append the user's id in this create action and not ask (neither add a `hidden_field` as suggested) for the user's id in the form.

```
def create
  card = Card.new(card_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
  if card.save
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    redirect_to some_other_path
  end
end
```